# Integral of product of Legendre polynomial $P_n(x)$ and shifted Legendre polynomial $\widetilde{P}_m(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, legendre-polynomials

Does the integral
$$C_{n,m}\equiv\int_0^1P_n(x)\widetilde{P}_m(x)dx$$
have any closed answer? $P_n(x)$ is the *Legendre polynomial* of order $n$. $\widetilde{P}_m(x)\equiv P_m(2x-1)$ is called the *shifted Legendre polynomial*.

For what $n$ and $m$, $C_{n,m}$ would vanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $P_n(x)$ in an explicit form [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):
$$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n}x^{n-2k}}$$
Write $\widetilde{P}_m(x)$ in an explicit form [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):
$$\widetilde{P}_m(x)=(-1)^m\sum_{j=0}^{l}{(-1)^j\binom{m}{j}\binom{m+j}{j}x^j}$$
Multiply and rearrange:
$$P_n(x)\widetilde{P}_m(x)=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n}}\sum_{j=0}^{l}{(-1)^j\binom{m}{j}\binom{m+j}{j}x^{n-2k+j}}$$
Integrate:
$$C_{n,m}\equiv\int_0^1P_n(x)\widetilde{P}_m(x)dx=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n}}\sum_{j=0}^{l}{(-1)^j\binom{m}{j}\binom{m+j}{j}\int_0^1x^{n-2k+j}}dx,$$
$$\int_0^1x^{n-2k+j}dx=\frac{1}{n-2k+j+1}x^{n-2k+j+1}\Big|_0^1=\frac{1}{n-2k+j+1},$$
solution:
$$\bbox[border:1px solid black]{
C_{n,m}=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n}}\sum_{j=0}^{l}{\frac{(-1)^j}{n-2k+j+1}\binom{m}{j}\binom{m+j}{j}}
}$$